# open PDF file in the browser window using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have PDF file located in the local file system,

local file path:

```
C:\pdf\sample.pdf
```

How do i open the pdf file in the browser using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help just follow the instructions and there is an example in the zip file try it.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-pdfviewer